# Why is super class empty constructor required but not called in a dreaded diamond situation?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I am trying to achieve the following design, which is a [dreaded diamond](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#virtual-inheritance-where) situation:

```
struct super_base
{
  super_base(int a) { b = a; }
  int b;
};

struct base : virtual super_base
{};

struct other_base : virtual super_base
{};

struct derived : base, other_base
{
  derived(int a) : super_base{a} {}
};

int main() {}
```

Which doesn't work. The error for the above code using Clang is quite
good at explaining the mistake:

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'base'
  derived(int a) : super_base{a} {}
  ^
note: default constructor of 'base' is implicitly deleted because base
      class 'super_base' has no default constructor
```

So I added an empty constructor for `super_base`, and it works:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdexcept>

struct super_base
{
  super_base() { throw std::logic_error{"Constructor should not be called."}; };
  super_base(int a) { b = a; }
  int b;
};

struct base : virtual super_base
{};

struct other_base : virtual super_base
{};

struct derived : base, other_base
{
  derived(int a) : super_base{a} {}
};

int main() { std::cout << derived(10).b << '\n'; }
```

But why does this not throw ?

P.S.: I purposefully used a dreaded diamond pattern to illustrate the use of virtual inheritance. The problem remains the same with single inheritance.

P.P.S.: The compiler used is Clang 3.9.1. The results are the same with
GCC 6.3.1.

Comment: Thanks to @Yakk's answer, I have now a clearer understanding of the problem. I think it comes from the order of the compiler stages.

There must be:

(1) first a stage selecting all the needed constructors (building implicit constructors if needed)

(2) then a stage discarding the unwanted constructor calls.

This would explain why the compiler attempts to build a constructor it
doesn't need.

I don't know if the compilers strictly follow the C++14 standard on this
point. I should dig into the standard and the compilers' code some day !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
struct base:super_base {}:
```

this tries to create some constructors.  One of them it tries to create is `base::base()`.

If `super_base` has no `super_base::super_base()`, this constructor is deleted.

If we have `super_base::super_base()=default` or `{}`, then `base::base()` by default exists, even if you don't `=default` it.

The same thing happens in `other_base`.

And your derived class tries to call the base object constructors, which are deleted, which gives you an error.

Now, why isn't it called?  When you have a virtual base class, the constructor is only called once.  Intermediate types which call the virtual base classes constructor have their calls ignored.

So we have `derived()` calling `base()`, `base()` calling `super_base()`, but that call is ignored because of virtual inheritance.

`derived()`'d call of `super_base(int)` is used instead.

Now, why are these the rules?  Because C++ doesn't have the concept of "constructor that can only be called if you are a derived class of this class explicitly calling a specific base constructor".  Virtual inheritance is not quite as full featured as you might like.